# Supplying arguments to MLEngine airflow operator

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-composer

I have been able to successfully train using the `gcloud ml-engine sumbit job` CLI. I then copied the "args" value from the console training input of the success job.

```
"args": [
    "--output_dir=gs://composer-models/flowers/trained_cnn",
    "--train_steps=1000",
    "--learning_rate=0.01",
    "--batch_size=40",
    "--model=cnn",
    "--augment",
    "--batch_norm",
    "--train_data_path=gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/train_set.csv",
    "--eval_data_path=gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/eval_set.csv"
  ]
```

However now when I try to supply these to run a job using the airflow `MLEngineTrainingOperator` I get the following error:
[image]

Even though the arguments are identical to those used in the succuessful run using `gcloud`.

This is the part that should parse the args in the `task.py` file:

```
  parser.add_argument(
      '--learning_rate',
      help='Initial learning rate for training',
      type=float,
      default=0.01
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments intended for the trainer should be passed to `training_args` of the `MLEngineTrainingOperator`.
Check for the documentation of the operator here.
http://airflow.apache.org/integration.html#mlenginetrainingoperator

From the error message, I suspect you added arguments for only `--learning_rate` and `--batch_size` in `task.py`?